# How do I update a varchar column that has a number by adding another number?

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, sql-update, sql-convert

I have a column that is varchar(80) and is storing dollar amounts (no $ sign). I would like to update the value by adding another amount, e.g. the existing amount is 96.73 and I want to add 1.00 to make 97.73.

I have tried cast and convert without any luck. I have tried:

```
set CAVALUETEXT = convert(INT, CAVALUETEXT) + 1.00
set CAVALUETEXT = cast(cavaluetext as int) + 1.00
```

and get the same error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '96.73' to data type int.

I think I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Why are you using unsupported software?  Also, fix your data model!  Don't store numbers in string columns.

Answer (score 2):

You *could* cast to `DECIMAL`, do the arithmetic, and then cast back to `VARCHAR`:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET CAVALUETEXT = CAST(
    CAST(CAVALUETEXT AS DECIMAL(19,2)) + 1.00 AS VARCHAR(21));
```

But the much better approach here would be to stop storing currency amounts, especially amounts on which you might need to do arithmetic, in a text columns.  Use a proper type for this like `DECIMAL(19,2)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CONVERT(float, [YOUR Varchar])`. For example `CONVERT(float, '0.123')` convert it to a float `0.123`. This only works on SQL Server.